# Grant Privileges and Create Public Synonym in Oracle

Tags: oracle, sql-grant, synonym

I have Views in Schema A and I want to create a Synonym for these views in Schema B.

Could you please help me write a query for Granting the role and creating a synonym?

Comment: Not able to Create Public Synonym directly due to no privilige

Comment: What does "grant the role" mean?  Are you able to log in both as A and B?

Comment: You don't need public synonyms for this.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp What would you advise on using if I need the views to be accessed from Schema A to B?

Comment: Gaz's answer is fine (grant select from A to B) except just remove the "PUBLIC", they don't need to be public synonyms. Schema B just needs the synonyms so it can refer to `viewname` instead of `A.viewname1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From user A, you only need to grant SELECT privilege to user A's views to user B

```
GRANT SELECT ON A.viewname1 TO B;
GRANT SELECT ON A.viewname2 TO B;
...
```

From B, creating synonyms allows reference to user A's views without the schema prefix ("A.").

```
CREATE SYNONYM viewname1 FOR A.viewname1;
CREATE SYNONYM viewname2 FOR A.viewname2;
...
```

It should now be possible for user B to select from those views like this:

```
SELECT * FROM viewname1;
```

*Note that a user can only use `CREATE SYNONYM` if they have the `CREATE SYNONYM` privilege.*

Comment: I don't recommend using public synonyms for this sort of thing. One day schema C will want to have its own version of `viewname1`, and you'll end up with a mess.

Comment: @Jeffrey: You are correct. I have edited the answer to reflect this.